# Where can I find align objects to pixel grid option in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cc-2018

[image]

I've already checked transform options 
and new documents option..I couldn't find it.

I just want to know where to check that options, not to snap option.

I want to know why I can't see that option.

Comment: Its been moved to the topmost righthand corner.

Answer (score 0):

It's at the top right options bar: two icons and a menu

[image]